# Struct 'State' cannot be used as an attribute

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, watchos

I have the following code in a `ContentView.swift` file:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedSpeed: Int = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}
```

*I have simplified it for the sake of readability. I know that `selectedSpeed` is not being used.*

In the line where `selectedSpeed` is declared, I'm getting the following error: **Struct 'State' cannot be used as an attribute**

Interestingly, pasting the exact same code in a Playground builds successfully. I'm on Xcode 12.1. I've tried the combo of nuking derived data and re-opening Xcode but the error persists. Any ideas what is wrong here?

Answer (score 41):

It turned out that I had a `struct` called `State` in my project and that caused the problem.

**TL;DR: Never call any of your structs, and potentially classes, State if you're planning on using SwiftUI**. I would expand it to not name any of your classes or structs with something that clashes with a property wrapper.

That also explains why everything was ok in the Playground.

The Report navigator was actually giving me the hint

[image]

Comment: Dang, TY. Same exact thing for me. Just changed my objects to: StateObj, CityObj and CountryObj just to be safe.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the reason behind this issue. You've just saved me hours of scratching my head.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That is the main reason why I decided to share in the first place! I had already lost a couple of hours understanding what was wrong :D

Answer (score 15):

The name `State` is not protected and as per your reply/answer you have `State` declared elsewhere, either in your own app or inside a dependency that you might be importing into that file.

You can tell the compiler what symbol to use by explicitly setting the correct "Namespace".

For example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @SwiftUI.State private var selectedSpeed: Int = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}
```

Comment: Turns out that the app that I currently maintained for the company that I work for uses State keyword long before SwiftUI is around. Your answer really helped me so that i dont have to do major refactor since it is used on a lot of places.